# ASP.NET Word Document without Office Automation

Tags: asp.net, automation, ms-word, ms-office

Is there any free library available for .NET that lets you read Microsoft Word documents in ASP.NET. As the interop assemblies aren't really meant for server usage, we are looking for a free solution that lets us read the contents of a doc file from an asp.net application

*Edit: should have specified, both .doc and .docx*

Answer (score 2):

If you can limit it to the Office 2007 & 2010 .docx format, you can use the [Microsoft Open XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Comment: was looking for both, but this is a good answer for the .docx format